# Custom adapter - using notifydatasetchanged with boolean array

Tags: android

I have created a custom adapter which has check boxes.
The state of the check boxes is stored in a boolean array, the size of which is defined in the adapter.

I call notifydatasetchanged in the onProgressUpdate of an async task. This means my list view gets updated every time there is something new added. The user can see stuff get added to the list without having to wait for the loop to complete.

Problem is, the boolean array size gets set to size of 1 in the custom adapter code, and it doesn't change, and therefore my code fails with array out of bounds when the position increments in the getView.

I am using code more or less identical to this:
This is the CustomAdapter I used:

```
//define your custom adapter
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>>
{
   // boolean array for storing
   //the state of each CheckBox 
   boolean[] checkBoxState;


   ViewHolder viewHolder;




public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> players) {

    //let android do the initializing :)
    super(context, textViewResourceId, players); 

  //create the boolean array with
   //initial state as false
  checkBoxState=new boolean[players.size()];
  }


    //class for caching the views in a row  
 private class ViewHolder
 {
   ImageView photo;
   TextView name,team;
   CheckBox checkBox;
 }



 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   if(convertView==null)
    {
   convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.players_layout, null);
   viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

    //cache the views
    viewHolder.photo=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
    viewHolder.name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    viewHolder.team=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.team);
    viewHolder.checkBox=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

     //link the cached views to the convertview
    convertView.setTag( viewHolder);


  }
  else
   viewHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


  int photoId=(Integer) players.get(position).get("photo");

  //set the data to be displayed
  viewHolder.photo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(photoId));
  viewHolder.name.setText(players.get(position).get("name").toString());
  viewHolder.team.setText(players.get(position).get("team").toString());

   //VITAL PART!!! Set the state of the 
   //CheckBox using the boolean array
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);// this will FAIL as position will increase


           //for managing the state of the boolean
           //array according to the state of the
           //CheckBox

           viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View v) {
    if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked())
     checkBoxState[position]=true;
    else
     checkBoxState[position]=false;

    }
   });

   //return the view to be displayed
   return convertView;
  }

 }
```

How can I handle the fact the boolean array will not increase in size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I handle the fact the boolean array will not increase in size?

This is a main disadvantage of static arrays<sup>1</sup> - they won't change their size dynamically when it's needed. Therefore in situations like this you should use dynamic array to avoid such a behaviour instead of static array(s).

So my suggestion is to **store your booleans in dynamic array** ( for instance in `List<Boolean>` ) and now it will make a trick.

<sup>1</sup>In some cases is very "neat" to use static array so static array - it's not bad structure but for your goal is not suitable.

Comment: Every time the adapter is updated, I will need to increase the list size, how could I do this and keep any existing items in the list

Comment: @user3437721 List size will be increased dynamically. So all what you need to add new values into List for every update.

Comment: I'm still confused as to where in my custom adapter I should set the list size?

Comment: @user3437721 at the beginning for example: `List<Boolean> checkBoxState = new ArrayList<Boolean>();`

Comment: But the List<Boolean> checkBoxState will always have a size of 0, how can I increase its size each time the adapter has new data, and also keep any existing boolean values in the List?

Comment: This was the part causing me the issue:  holder.checkbox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);

Comment: @user3437721 ... you need to add booleans into List (each boolean will represent checkbox in row).